# pg_notify with a subset of a row

Tags: postgresql, triggers

Hi I am trying to work out how to return a subset of a new row as json to a pg_notify function.

I am currently using

```
create or replace function public.notify_site()
returns trigger
language plpgsql
as $function$
begin
perform pg_notify('ppsite', row_to_json(NEW)::text);
      RETURN new;
    END;
$function$;
```

which works fine returning the entire row of data when the after insert trigger for the table fines, however, what I'm trying to do is return just a subset of NEW rather than the entire thing.  It would be really cool if I could return the result of a select on NEW or something similar. Is this possible or does my receiving application need to sort the data out instead?

To be clear, I want to return json with say

NEW.c1, NEW.c2, NEW.c5 rather than the entire row of about 50 values.

Ta.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can define the projection you want from the NEW record:

```
 CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION public.notify_site()
 RETURNS trigger
 LANGUAGE plpgsql
AS $function$
    declare
      my_record record;
    begin
      select NEW.id as id, NEW.some_data as some_data INTO my_record;
      perform pg_notify('pp_site', row_to_json(my_record)::text);
      return NEW;
    end;
$function$
;
```